VisionOS - Set entity position around the hand's wrist
I'm working on a VisionOS app but I'm a bit stuck on placing a watch usdz on hand’s wrist within an immersive space.
What I want:

User click on image
A ModelEntity with usdz file appears on the wrist as the user is wearing watch
Watch should rotate and move as the hand is moving.
The issue I'm having is not able to strap the watch usdz on wrist as if user is wearing it.
Here's my code so far:

func processHandUpdates() async {
        for await update in handTracking.anchorUpdates {

            let handAnchor = update.anchor
            
            guard handAnchor.isTracked else { continue }
            let fingerTip = handAnchor.handSkeleton?.joint(.wrist)
            guard ((fingerTip?.isTracked) != nil ) else { continue  }
            let originFromWrist = handAnchor.originFromAnchorTransform
            watch[handAnchor.chirality]?.setTransformMatrix(originFromWrist,relativeTo:nil)
            watch[handAnchor.chirality]?.setScale([0.01, 0.01, 0.01], relativeTo: nil)
        }
    }


Please check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/happybeam this code. HeartGestureModel.swift file. if it gets help
